# Firebase Recycler adapter doesn't show data, but load images

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to code my adapter with Firebase. The problem: RecyclerView loading only images, but another information is empty. I don't know what's the problem because Android Studio doesn't show any errors. Only something like this, but in blue:

```
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Date found on class com.boiko.taisiia.praca.Model.Dates
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for Name found on class com.boiko.taisiia.praca.Model.Dates
```

This is my POJO class:

```
public class Dates {
    private String DataName, Data, Image;
    public  Dates(){};
    public Dates(String dataName,String data, String image){
    DataName = dataName;
    Data = data;
    Image = image;
}

public String getDataName() {
    return DataName;
}

public void setDataName(String dataName) {
    DataName = dataName;
}

public String getData() {
    return Data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    Data = data;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}
}
```

This is ViewHolder:

```
public class DatesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView data_img;
    public TextView data_name;
    public TextView data;


    public DatesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        data_img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_img);
        data_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_name);
        data = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class DatesList extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dataList;


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Dates, DatesViewHolder> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dates_list);

        //Firebase implementation
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dataList = database.getReference().child("Dates");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_dates);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        loadListDates();
    }

    private void loadListDates() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Dates, DatesViewHolder>(Dates.class, R.layout.date_item, DatesViewHolder.class, dataList) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(DatesViewHolder viewHolder, Dates dataList, int i) {
                viewHolder.data_name.setText(dataList.getDataName());
                viewHolder.data.setText(dataList.getData());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(dataList.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.data_img);

            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Database:

```
    "Dates":{

    "01":{
        "Name": "Magicians",
        "Date": "1.02.2018",
        "Image": "http://ex-fs.net/uploads/posts/2017-01/1485425221_0503512.jpg"
    },
    "02":{
        "Name": "Grimm",
        "Date": "3.03.2018",
        "Image": "http://ex-fs.net/uploads/posts/2015-10/1446316149_grimm.jpg"
    },
    "03":{
        "Name": "Stranger Things",
        "Date": "25.04.2018",
        "Image": "http://ex-fs.net/uploads/posts/2017-01/1483352456_homeland.jpg"
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database you have `Name`, `Date`, `Image`,  you need to change them in the database to lower case to become like this `name`, `date` and `image`.

Then use the below POJO class:

```
public class Dates {
private String date, name, image;
public  Dates(){};
public Dates(String date,String name, String image){
this.name=name;
this.date=date;
this.image=image;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name=name;
 }

public String getDate() {
  return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
  this.date=date;
}

 public String getImage() {
   return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
  this.image=image;
 }
}
```